# Intel XDK: document.location.href leads to the wrong page

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

Hello Stack Overflow Community, I've been searching and trying out different things and nothing seems to work. In my Intel XDK project, when I try using location.location.href = "#EndGame" or other forms of it, the page does change but it changes to a different page than the one I asked it to, in my case it changed to the "mainpage". It happened properly when I used a button but not with JavaScript. I checked my code and I don't think there's anything in there that should cause a problem. So is this a bug? If it is one, can you suggest for me a way around it?

I'm not very advanced in JavaScript and HTML5 so this might seem like a bad question.

This is the button:

```
<a class="button widget uib_w_3 d-margins PictWid" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="Start" style=" margin:0px auto;display:block" onclick="GameLoading()" href="#GamePlay" data-transition="fade">Start</a>
```

This is the js code:

```
    function GameOver()
{
     window.clearInterval(Timer);
    window.clearInterval(Timer2);
 w4=0
    for (i = 0; i < level; i++) 
    {
        CenterX[w4] = -100;
        CenterY[w4] = -100;
        w4+=1;
    }

    ShowGold();
    Draw1();

    level=0;
m=0;
k=0;
k2=0;
x3= 0+24.72;
y3 = hei2 - 24.72;
vx=0;
vy=0;
x2 = wid2/2;
y2 = hei2/2;
x = wid2/2;
y = hei2/2;

    setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "#EndGame"},500);
    EndGamePage();
}

function EndGamePage()
{
     wid2 = screen.width;
    hei2 = screen.height;
    wid = screen.width - 20;
    hei = screen.height - 20;
if (wid < hei)
{   
    //alert("Testing2!")
    document.getElementById("Title2").style.width = wid + "px";
    document.getElementById("Start2").style.width = wid + "px";
    document.getElementById("Title2").style.marginTop = hei2*0.15 + "px";

} else
{
   // alert("Testing3!")
    document.getElementById("Title2").style.width =  hei + "px";
    document.getElementById("Start2").style.width = hei + "px";
    document.getElementById("Title2").style.marginTop = wid2*0.15 + "px";
} 

}
```

Comment: document.location.hash = '#EndGame' ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Unfortunately while trying to link it to another html file(which was not the answer), I deleted my main.js by mistake. Darn it, 2 weeks of work. I think the reason might be that there was an logical error in my js file that I couldn't find. BTW I did try document.location.hash = '#EndGame'.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
location.hash = "#EndGame";
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working (I have the same problem that OP has)

Answer (score 0):

You cant make a link handle both href and a function to trigger on click , so the proper solution is to add this line to your function `GameLoading()` , or call a new function from within that function:

```
window.location+="/#EndGame"
```

Not sure if this gonna work with intel XDK or not , but worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

After 6 months worth of experience, I found out that the best way, for me, is to use what's called a "show" function/method. Here it is:

```
    function show(shown, hidden, hidden2, hidden3, hidden4) {
        document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(hidden2).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(hidden3).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(hidden4).style.display = 'none';

        return false;
    }
```

What it does is it just shows or hide specified div if you give it their ids. So in a button, you could have:

```html
<a onclick="show('pagetwo', 'pagezero', 'pagethree', 'pageone', 'pagefour');" id='Start' class="ui-btn">Start</a>
```